# Disable global fitering for particular variables

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have set global_xss_filtering to TRUE in my config file. Is it possible to disable xss filtering for particular data - lets say I want to disable xss filtering for 'title' post  variable.

Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as far as I know there's a little hack you can make. 
You go to the input class (system/core/input.php) and change the default value of the $xss_clean parameter. 
Natively it is set to FALSE, so that you can choose to change it by passing TRUE to $this->input->post() or get().

Example with post() (at line 128 of input.php), but you need to apply to the get also.

```
/**
    * Fetch an item from the POST array
    *
    * @access   public
    * @param    string
    * @param    bool
    * @return   string
    */
    function post($index = NULL, $xss_clean = TRUE)   // <-- Here I changed the default from FALSE to TRUE)
    {
        // Check if a field has been provided
        if ($index === NULL AND ! empty($_POST))
        {
            $post = array();

            // Loop through the full _POST array and return it
            foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $key)
            {
                $post[$key] = $this->_fetch_from_array($_POST, $key, $xss_clean);
            }
            return $post;
        }

        return $this->_fetch_from_array($_POST, $index, $xss_clean);
    }
```

Now, you turn OFF the global filtering (set it to FALSE). Now, your input will be automaticlaly filtered, unless you specify FALSE as the second parameter of the call, like `$this->input->post('title',FALSE).`

You might alternatively (instead of hacking the core) want to **extend** the native input library so that you pass a TRUE instead of FALSE, something along the line of this:

```
class MY_Input extends CI_Input {

    function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    //........

    function get($index = NULL, $xss_clean = TRUE)
    {
        return parent::get($index, $xss_clean);
    }

    //...........

    function post($index = NULL , $xss_clean = TRUE)
    {
        return parent::post($index, $xss_clean);
    }

}
```

It should be working in the same way, and you won't need to hack the core file everytime you change it. 
Read the [extending the core](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html) page on the manual for better infos.